# Best way to get information about errors in python

Tags: python

I'm learning about python. I'm doing and application to monitoring voltage and I found that sometimes when you rise and error the final information about this error is not enough to understand it, when it happens. My question is: What is the best way to give the information?

For example, I know that I can do something like that:

```
class IncorrectVoltageError(Exception):
    pass

raise IncorrectVoltageError('Incorrect voltage, should be 5V')

>>IncorrectVoltageError: Incorrect voltage, should be 5V
```

but if it will be a common error in my code maybe the information could be in the class explain.

```
class IncorrectVoltageError(Exception):
    '''Incorrect voltage, should be 5V'''
    pass

raise IncorrectVoltageError(IncorrectVoltageError.__doc__)

>>IncorrectVoltageError: Incorrect voltage, should be 5V
```

What is the best way? And are there other ways?

Thanks

Comment: Have you looked at this [tutorial](https://www.python-course.eu/python3_exception_handling.php) about exception handling? [Or this one?](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_exceptions.htm)

Answer (score 2):

The common way is to override a specific method from the parent class. In that case, it is `__init__` method.

Something like this:

```
class IncorrectVoltageError(Exception):
    def __init__(self, message=None, *args, **kwargs):
        if not message:
            message = "Incorrect voltage, should be 5V"
        super().__init__(message, *args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Sorry, can you explain me your last line? And how should be used this exception class? Thanks for your time

Comment: The last line invokes the rest of parent method. Therefore you don't need to repeat all logic but just add customization you need.